# Compiler presenting errors although Scanner is imported?

Tags: netbeans, java.util.scanner, system.in

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class System {

    public static void main(String[]args){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String cName, cContact, cAddress, cIC, cDob, cGender;
        int i; 
    }
}
```

Sorry if this was a repost, but i've searched high and low for a good answer, some suggested having to import java.util.Scanner which i already have, the problem is compiler kept having the error at line `Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);`

```
"cannot find symbol
symbol: variable in 
location: class System"
```

?! is the library corrupted or something? using NetBeans IDE 8.0.1.

Answer (score 1):

Try not to use the names System or Scanner for your public class or any other class in your project.
For example:

import java.util.Scanner;

public class ChangeName{  //change the name of the class here. do not name it System or Scanner

```
public static void main(String[]args){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String cName, cContact, cAddress, cIC, cDob, cGender;
    int i; 
}
```

}

I hope this help you!